# Create Silverlight custom control with code only (no xaml)

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I would like to create a Silverlight custom control using C# only, without any xaml.

Here is my work so far (stripped down to the bare minimum for the question):

I tried to inherit User control as follows:

```
public class myControl: UserControl
{
    // class code
}
```

And adding it to the LayoutRoot:

```
myControl control = new myControl();
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(control);
```

The control is added, but its invisible!!

How can i make it visible ? Is there something i missed ?

edit: The only visual element in my contorl is a grid with an image background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Usercontrol` will be empty and have no visual effect until you give it a child control via it's `Content` property.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it :), i defined the grid inside of the class, i just needed to add it to the Content like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you put a template in place or add elements in code, UserControl is empty.

Maybe you could try inheriting from an existing control which has a template, like Button, etc and change that in code?